# How to access android avd devices internal storage

Tags: android-emulator, storage, avd-manager

I have some data inside the android emulator. Is there any way to access android avd devices internal storage on PC

Answer (score 4):

Go to Emulator:

`Settings -> Memory -> Internal Storage -> Other`

Then a pop up will open. Click on explore. Then you will get access of Internal Storage.

or

check this in android studio -

```
View > Tool Windows > Device File Explorer
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: There is no Memory option  inside Settings

Comment: i think that may be due to different emulators.i have updtaed another path.you can try that once.